# Angular JS promise then() not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to read data from websql. The code works well when I put everything in the controller but it does not return any result when I moved the code into separate service. I want to get data from the Service rather than from controller.

javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', '$q', function ($scope, myService, $q) {
        $scope.count = 0;
        $scope.connect = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
  myService.method1().then(function(results){
              $scope.count = results.rows.length;
                },
            function (error) {
            console.log("Error");
            }
        );
 }])

myApp.service('myService', function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    this.method1 = function() {
                     var db = openDatabase('mydb2', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
         var msg;

         db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (3, "foobar")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (4, "logmsg")');
            msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
            document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
         });

         db.transaction(function (tx) {
           tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
                 if(results.rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Inside resolve");
                 deferred.resolve(results);
                 $scope.$apply();
               } else {
                    deferred.reject(response);
               }
            }, null);
         });

         return deferred.promise;
        };

});
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
{{count}}

  <div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pc97fgfg/9/

Comment: the fiddle is pointless because it can't possibly run

Comment: does `console.log("Inside resolve");` get executed?

Comment: in this line, `deferred.reject(response);` - what is `response` ? seems to be a variable plucked from thin air

Comment: FYI you would want to create your deferred object (`var deferred = $q.defer();`) inside `method1` not outside. You would have issues with multiple requests otherwise. Is the error handler running? Do you get an exception in the console?

Comment: Yes. `console.log("Inside resolve");` get executed.

Comment: Inject $rootScope and use $rootScope.$apply();  var deferred = $q.defer(); should be placed in method1 . http://jsfiddle.net/nrp7ycc4/

Comment: Thanks for Input for `method1`. I am not getting any exception. But yes I will correct the code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected result by using `$rootScope.$apply();` after `deferred.resolve(results);`.

Updated fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/pc97fgfg/14/

Thanks neda for suggestion.